# Beautiful Soup Remove Tag Error

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

So I'm scraping some content and I'm trying to strip out the html tags with beautifulsoup in python, but leave the content.  For example, given:

```
<p>Hello, how <b>are</b> you</p>
```

I would want output:

```
Hello, how are you
```

Normally, I would use the get_text method.  The problem is that apparently some of the pages I'm scraping have html errors in them.  For example:

```
<p>Hello, how </b><b>are</b> you</p>
```

When this happens, get_text() winds up stripping out big sections of the text I want. I tried doing this with regex instead and wound up with the same problem:

```
    description = re.sub("<.[^/<>]*>", "", str(description))    
    description = re.sub("</.[^/<>]*>", "", str(description))
```

Does anyone know a way around this issue?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: BeautifulSoup handles broken HTML by leaving it to the parser to make sense of it. Different parsers make different sense from broken HTML. Try using a [different parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) on your content.

Comment: That did it!  I used htlm5lib instead of the default parser, and that fixed the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup trees represent all elements as objects; you cannot use regular expressions to 'fix' broken HTML after the tree was built.

BeautifulSoup leaves it to a parser to build the tree, and it is up to the parser to decide how to handle broken HTML. Different parsers handle broken HTML differently.

You should try [different parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) with your input to see how they'll handle your input. The standard `html.parser` option handles broken HTML less well than other options, while the `html5lib` option is closest to how a modern browser would handle broken HTML, albeit at a slower rate than `lxml` would handle HTML parsing.